# Pausing and resuming coroutines for downloading a file

Tags: android, kotlin, asynchronous, kotlin-coroutines

I would like to download a file using coroutine and would like to implement a pause and a resume functionality for this downloading process. I know coroutine use a continuation and it has a resume method, but I am not aware about a pause and then a resume functionality.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with coroutines. You should use `DownloadManager` class for that. It offers pause and resume functionality.
Coroutines' pause and resume features are for function's execution using `Continuation` class at the core.